# Azure APIM Policy - When to use <backend> </backend>

Tags: azure, policy, azure-api-management

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-policies

```
    <policies>
  <inbound>
    <!-- statements to be applied to the request go here -->
  </inbound>
  <backend>
    <!-- statements to be applied before the request is forwarded to 
         the backend service go here -->
  </backend>
  <outbound>
    <!-- statements to be applied to the response go here -->
  </outbound>
  <on-error>
    <!-- statements to be applied if there is an error condition go here -->
  </on-error>
</policies>
```

When do we use backend sections in the policy?

Looks like setting the backend url using   is also done on `<inbound>` node only.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

that part is used to do any transforms\checks on the request before forwarding it to the backend, for example I was adding headers to the request and validating oauth tokens.

Comment: But you can do all this in the inbound as well, right?

Comment: i think you should be, not sure, way too much time without exposure to APIM